# Nested If-else issue

Tags: bash, shell, search, if-statement

I want to do following things:

1. For all the cube names in CUBE , check whether there is .zip file
   (${C}28052014.zip) under directory /data/testing/CUBE_Name/ if yes
   then echo echo "'$C','SUCCESS'"
2. If not then for all the cube names for which .zip file not found in
   Point-1, check whether the string 'files have been truncated' is
   there in their respective .log file ($C.log) under directory
   /archive/logs/CUBE_Name/ If yes then echo "'$C','TRUNCATED'"
3. If not then for all the cube names for which string not found in
   Point-2, echo "'$C','FAILED'"

I've created my script as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
CUBE="DAPP TAPP PAPP CAPP"

for C in $CUBE
do
cd /data/testing/$C/

test -f ${C}28052014.zip

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then

        echo "'$C','SUCCESS'" >> /data/testing/out.log
else
cd /archive/logs/$C/

if grep -q 'files have been truncated' $C.log;
then

       echo "'$C','TRUNCATED'" >> /data/testing/out.log
else
       echo "'$C','FAILED'" >> /data/testing/out.log

fi
fi
done
```

The problem I'm facing here is...

My script is repeatedly checking for all the Cube Names to do the work mentioned under above 3 Points, which is not desired.It is supposed to exclude the cube names for which required test has been successful in previous step and should only look for the cubes for which test is not successful in last step.

Comment: What is `#!/bin/sh` on your system? Also seems like you could simplify the cd/test/exit-status-check with just `if [ -f full_path ] `. And what is `$28052014.zip`? Because most shells will assume it's a variable.

Comment: I'm concerned about the `$C$28052014.zip`. The second `$` would cause bash to substitute the 28052014th command-line argument. I think you want `${C}28052014.zip`.

Comment: @chrisaycock Sorry..that was a typo..corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slight simplification. Don't really need the nesting at all (i.e. `elif`, but kept it if you wanted it). Also spacing doesn't really matter, but tried to make it more readable, and I wouldn't use capital variables to avoid conflict with environment variables.

```
#!/bin/sh
cube="DAPP TAPP PAPP CAPP"

for c in $cube
do
  if [ -f "/data/testing/$c/${c}28052014.zip" ]
  then
    echo "'$c','SUCCESS'" >> /data/testing/out.log
  else
    if grep -q 'files have been truncated' "/archive/logs/$c/$c.log"
    then
      echo "'$c','TRUNCATED'" >> /data/testing/out.log
    else
      echo "'$c','FAILED'" >> /data/testing/out.log
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: Nice! I'd put `/data/testing/out.log` into a variable instead of repeating 3 times.